# Getting timeout error when reading subreddit json

Tags: python, reddit

I'm getting timeout error when reading subreddit json

Code (it works fine with other json data):

```
import requests
import json

myHeaders={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36"}
textData = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/Justrolledintotheshop/top.json", headers=myHeaders).content
jsonData = json.loads(textData)

print(jsonData)
```

output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
> line 156, in _new_conn
> conn = connection.create_connection(   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py",
> line 84, in create_connection
> raise err   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py",
> line 74, in create_connection
> sock.connect(sa) TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 665, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 376, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 994, in _validate_conn
> conn.connect()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
> line 300, in connect
> conn = self._new_conn()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
> line 168, in _new_conn
> raise NewConnectionError( urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10d258f40>:
> Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

I'm with Mac & python 3.8, I did some research but didn't find the answer yet, anyone experienced can help?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to work on my system. Might be some problem with you internet connection, perhaps a proxy

Comment: Yep, I tried with proxy, it works fine now.